# Parse 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, forms, parse-platform, javascript

I have looked into the various ways of sending an email through a form on a static site. This way here @ https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-static-websites-using-parse/ looked the best for me! Loved the tutorial..Good stuff from Martyn Daviesonon how to do deploy cloud code and use the javascript api from parse. Thanks for sharing Martyn :)

However I have ran into an issue with actually getting this to work properly...I really want to use this method but it just needs a little fixing.

Currently I am having this error pop up in my console.
It's a 400 bad request..
When I click on the link to emailer.js:28 it takes to to this in my code. This is where the error is seems to be happening in emailer.js

[image]

```
  error: function(object, error) {
    console.log(error);
    $('#response').html('Error! Email not sent!').addClass('error').fadeIn('fast');
  }
```

Lastly I don't have an email set up for my domain name. This is because I am still building this site on gh-pages. The email that I am using while I test this function is my gmail email. Is this also a potential issue? When I actually deploy this site I will use a domain name email.

Comment: your POST is malformed its not correct hence its crapping out on the server, recheck the API documentation or point me to it

Comment: It's not appropriate to expect anyone to go to an external link to see your code. Post all relevant code within question. Also your link will change in time making it useless for future readers with similar problems. Questions should be self contained

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for you're feed back. Your point is completely understandable :) I just add the link so people can tinker with my file. So to clear things up..I no longer should include links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first.

You **really** should remove your Parse.com credentials from your `email.js` file since from the moment you posted access to that file, *anyone can use your account for pretty much any unsavory thing they fancy*. Just saying.

Next, your `email.js` file appears to call a server-side/cloud function called `sendEmail` via parse.com's REST API but you do not appear to define that function anywhere. At least, it's not in your `email.js` file. Did you already do this? Did you apply for the proper credentials from `sendgrid` to allow you access to their API?

The article you mention as your inspiration defines a sendEmail() function that calls the REST API at `sendgrid` to actually deliver email messages. This function is then deployed to the cloud server using the parse.com's `Parse.cloud.define()` function.

If you haven't done this, then there is no function for you to call via `https://api.parse.com/1/functions/sendEmail`.

Comment: thank you for your solid advice here..So I've just removed the app keys. One question about that tho..How can this work if I remove the app keys? Don't I need them to make this whole process work? Is there a way to hind the emailer.js file?

Comment: For what I know right now it seems to me that I am calling the function here `Parse.Cloud.run("sendEmail", data, {
      success: function(object) {
        $('#response').html('Email sent!').addClass('success').fadeIn('fast');
      },` is this not calling the function?

Comment: I'm really confused here..Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Brent, I suggested you remove the app keys to hide them from persons who would do you harm. They are definitely needed in your running code, just not in code you choose to expose via StackOverflow.

Comment: @Brent, yes, you are indeed attempting to call a function using `Parse.Cloud.run`, but you haven't defined the function you're calling. `sendEmail` is something you have to write yourself and then register with your server via `Parse.Cloud.define()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to write sendMail. Can you please post me a jsfiddle with how to write that correctly?

Comment: `Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmail", function(request, response) {
 var sendgrid = require('sendgrid');` I think I am already doing it correct?

Comment: The article you refer to as your inspiration contains an example implementation of sendEmail()

Comment: I have no idea how to do this...I'd really appreciate if you could show some me where exactly I need to add this line `sendEmail` You're welcome to fork my repo if you want

Comment: @Brent, what Rob said the problem is - not having sendEmail defined - is the problem, and you can see an example of what sendEmail should be in my article at https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-static-websites-using-parse - however if you're still having problems, let me know and I'll jump on a call with you and help you out.